# With SQL (mysql) Append the results of one sub-query to that of another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two mysql tables.  And essentially two queries (one to each table) that I want to combine within a single SQL Query.  Seems like it should be easy (kind of like an inner Join) But inner join is DUPLICATING non-uniqe values from table 2 into my results array...  I dont want them duplicated... I want those duplicates from table/query 2 *combined into* the result record of query1

Query 1 Gets records from table 1. Results are unique. (one ID returns one record) It's simply returning all fields on records where an ID is equal to one of my conditions. [Im using IN instead of a bunch of OR's)

```
$sid = "'M-179','M-242','M-231','Q-2thru5'" ; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE IN ($sid)`
```

Query 2 gets records from table 2. But results are NOT unique. One ID can return many records.

```
$query2 = "SELECT extra_data, pub_url FROM table2 WHERE IN ($sid)";
```

So I want EACH extra_data & pub_url field from ALL returned records just slapped onto the end of the query 1 result.  Am I making sense?  So the result would look something like this...

```
[0] => Array
        (
            * all my returned fields from the 
             record returned by query 1 here
            $row['extra_data']  
            $row['pub_url']  <-returned record from query 2
            $row['extra_data'] 
            $row['pub_url']  <-another returned record from query 2
            $row['extra_data'] 
            $row['pub_url']  <-any another returned 
                              record from query 2, etc..
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *combining* the result?

Do you want the results from query2 to appear in the same
relevant rows but just extra columns, or you want them to 
appear as new rows.

For the first case, you will have to use `JOIN`.

But I have a feeling that what you want to do is the second
case.  In this case, you will have to use `UNION`.  Note, however,
that in this case the columns of the two queries must match.  So
the union of two queries would look like this:

```
-- pseudo code only
SELECT extra_data, pub_url FROM table1 WHERE IN ($sid)
union
SELECT extra_data, pub_url FROM table2 WHERE IN ($sid)
```

Comment: Yes, the first case. Not the second. I want results of the second sub-query to table2 to appear in the same relevant rows as extra columns.....  It would be like adding extra_data2, pub_url2, extra_data3, pub_url3, extra_data4, pub_url4 to the first table's results...   (but as I mentioned, JOIN and INNER JOIN did not work, because it just duplicated the results of table 1 for each result of table2...

Comment: For each `sid`, is there exactly one row in `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: no...  for each matching .sid row in table one, there can be two or three or more .sid matching rows in table 2.  Thus my problem.  I want only ONE row returned for each matching sid.  So if table 2 has 3 matching rows... I want the columns and results of those rows added into the table one row

Comment: Show us some examples how the result set should look like.  How do you want the data from three rows combined into one?

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this, which would join the results of table 1 to table 2 on the column containing the sid value.

```
SELECT a.*, b.extra_data, pub_url
FROM table1 a
left outer join table2 b on a.sid = b.sid 
WHERE a.sid IN ($sid)
```